# Validate window form using C#

Tags: c#, forms, validation

I am new to C#

I am trying to validate a form using C#. I want a `MessageBox` to show when validation failed. I have the error:

> "No overload method 'UserFormValidation '"

The code is below

```
// Validation Method
public void UserFormValidation(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (textSurname.Text == " ")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please insert your Surname");            
    }
    else if (textFirstname.Text == " ")
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please insert your Firstname");   
    }
}

private void UserRegistrationSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //  Call the validation Method

       UserFormValidation();

    // if validation pass print message below

       MessageBox.Show("User Registed", "User Message");      
}
```

Comment: UserFormValidation(sender,e);

Comment: @Toumash -- How do you know that `e` is a `CancelEventArgs`?

Answer (score 3):

You have defined your `UserFormValidation` method with parameters:

```
public void UserFormValidation(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
```

But you're calling it without parameters:

```
UserFormValidation();
```

One way to fix this is to change the method signature so it takes no parameters as long as you don't really need them -- which it looks like from your present code.  Another way is to simply give it parameters when you're calling it:

```
UserFormValidation(this, new CancelEventArgs());
```

A third option would be to add an overload that takes no parameters, thus keeping the one that does intact in case you're using it elsewhere.  Inside your overload, you could simply call the one that takes params:

```
public void UserFormValidation()
{
    UserFormValidation(this, new CancelEventArgs());
}
```

Which one you choose ultimately depends on how you're using it.

Comment: Thanks Rory for your help the error is gone now but the validation is not working when click send on the form. I left the text box empty. Any help please.

Comment: What happens when you debug and step through the code?  The debugger is a powerful thing...

Comment: Nothing Happen just jump  direct to the message box

Comment: Which one?  You have three.  Step through the code line by line.  F11.

Comment: Sorry   MessageBox.Show("User Registed", "User Message");

Comment: Well did you step through the code as I suggested?  I think you'll find it goes into your `UserFormValidation` method and doesn't stop on either `if` or `else if` because neither of those conditions are met.  You should step through the code and stop ignoring my suggestion to do that because its an important one.  When you're doing that, you can look at the "locals" or the "autos" window to see what your variables and controls have for values.

Comment: I ran the Debug. Look like the code is not executing the  if statement in UserFormValidation. Look like the condition is true all the time the code is run. Any suggestion how to make the code check the condition. Thanks

Comment: The only way it could skip both the `if` block and the `else if` block is if `textSurname.Text == " "` is *not* true (maybe `textSurName` has two spaces instead of just one?) and also `textFirstname.Text == " "` is *not* true (same reason?).  Be careful when you're checking; what you have currently is only checking for a *single* space char in both cases.  If you want to check to see if the user hasn't entered anything or has entered something but its one or more space characters, you should use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(textSurname.Text)` and `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(textFirstname.Text)`.

Comment: Thanks rory one more question if you don't mind. The validation worked but the code doesn’t stop. I want to return false when the validation failed

Comment: So instead of a `void` for return type, use `bool`, and then add a `return false;` statement wherever necessary.

Comment: Hi rory The validation work but doesn’t exit when failed thanks for your help

public void UserFormValidation(object sender, EventArgs e)
           
        {
           bool exit = false;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSurname.Text))
            {
                Error message;
               exit = true;
  
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstname.Text))
           {
       Error message;
              exit = true; 
          }
        }

Answer (score 0):

It is because your method UserFormValidatin needs 2 parameters, and you call it without parameters

Answer (score -1):

Just call

```
UserFormValidation(sender, new CancelEventArgs());
```

If you want to validate the form controls you could do it with ValidateChildren() Method.

Please take a look at the msdn sample code:

[[1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158374(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158374(v=vs.110).aspx)

The other problem is

> if (textSurname.Text == " ")

This condition is True, if you have exactly 1 whitespace.

You have to do it like that way:

```
if (IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textSurname.Text))
{...}
```

Comment: `e` is a `System.EventArgs` and `UserFormValidation` takes a `CancelEventArgs`.  If `e` is not a `CancelEventArgs` a runtime exception will occur.